# Mobile-like push navigation using Polymer

Tags: polymer

I've been trying to find a practical example about this, however all Polymer examples doesn't have multiple pages within its navigation, as moderate or big Mobile App could have.

I tried using some JS to add nodes to a `<core-pages>` component and updating the `<core-toolbar>`, however it doesn't look as an scalable approach for this.

What's the correct approach for this using Polymer components?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put together a few demos showing how to route with Polymer. https://github.com/erikringsmuth/polymer-router-demos

This is just a starting point. There are many other ways including manually wiring it up in a `<script>`.

Comment: Thanks, your response was quite helpful to redirect me to some frameworks as `flatiron-director` that can be use for this. I've found an example of it also here: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/yeoman/